# lua 5.2 with with integer numbers only

Tags: lua

I need to compile Lua 5.2 with int numbers only.  I still see some places where double is used?

Is there a list of places to change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit [luaconf.h](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/lua/local/source/5.2/luaconf.h.html#LUAL_BUFFERSIZE) to change several macros starting at `LUA_NUMBER is the type of numbers in Lua`. It's not complicated.

Comment: Thanks for the link, the hyperlinks of defines are *GREAT*.

Comment: @Ayman, please report back on how this worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: Just open luaconf.  Look for the '@@' macros that you need to change.  What is very important is to also check the LUA_ANSI and __STRICT_ANSI__ macros.